# How to make values of an axis show clearly in pgf plots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following LaTeX code I wrote:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Execution Time Using Varying Array Sizes },
    xlabel={Array Length},
    ylabel={Execution Time [milliseconds]},
    xmin=0, xmax=1000000,
    ymin=0, ymax=30,
    xtick={0,1000,10000,100000,1000000},
    ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1000,4.1)(10000,4.2)(100000,6.6)(1000000,26.0)
    };

    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

My problem is that the x-axis values don't show clearly, here is a picture that showcases it:
[image: problem]

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated, I have already tried playing around with the code like doing things such as switching axis, etc...

Comment: You expect to see clearly your x ticks, but you chose a linear scale, which is not suitable for this kind of range (1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000).

Comment: Switch from your `axis` to a `semilogxaxis` environment. Therefore you show the first x values although they are very close to each other in comparison to the last one.

Comment: @SebGlav I have no idea how to change this to a logarithmic scale, thought it would do this on its own when seeing the vlaues

Comment: @Venez I kept everything the same but changed
\begin{axis} and \end{axis}
to \begin{semilogaxis} and \end{semilogaxis} and I got environment undefined

I tried loglogaxis which worked but gave awkward values for the y axis obviously so I would rather make it semilog

Comment: Try `semlogxaxis` (in detail: `semilogXaxis`) and it should work. Also an advice for the future: read the pgfplot documentation and do not fear its many pages/examples, because they want to help you.

Comment: @Venez thank you, please post this as an answer so I accept it and give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[
title={Execution Time Using Varying Array Sizes },
xlabel={Array Length},
ylabel={Execution Time [milliseconds]},
xmin=0, xmax=1000000,
ymin=0, ymax=30,
xtick={0,1000,10000,100000,1000000},
ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,30},
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot[color=blue,mark=square] coordinates {
    (1000,4.1)(10000,4.2)(100000,6.6)(1000000,26.0)
};
\end{semilogxaxis} % beware the two X letters in semilogxaxis
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]